# Move caret line start/end in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to remap moving the caret to the beginning/end of a line of text, as what <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> are doing right now. However, I'm unable to find which commands actually control this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you press `Home` in the **Press shortcut keys** field of the keyboard options dialog, it shows the corresponding command **Edit.LineStart**:

[image]

Similarly for `End` the command is **Edit.LineEnd**.